# downloading file using a link

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [downloading files using php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124450/downloading-files-using-php-and-mysql)

hi im a newbie in php and mysql. i uploaded a folder in my server and it stored different resume now im trying to download them using a link.

```
 <?php

       $host="xxxx"; // Host name 
       $username="xxxx"; // Mysql username 
       $password="xxxx"; // Mysql password 
       $db_name="xxxx"// Database name 

       // Connect to server and select databse.
       $conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot 
       connect"); 
       mysql_select_db("$db_name");
       $query="SELECT * FROM userinfo";

         $result=mysql_query($query);
         $num=mysql_numrows($result);


             $i=0;

             while ($i < $num) {

             $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"FirstName");
             $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"MiddleName");
             $f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"LastName");
             $f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"EmailAdd");
             $f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"Nationality");
             $f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"Street");
             $f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"City");
             $f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"Region");
             $f9=mysql_result($result,$i,"Mobile");
             $f10=mysql_result($result,$i,"ExamResult");
             $f11=mysql_result($result,$i,"res");

             ?>
             <tr   onmousedown="HighLightTR(this,'#A0A0A0  ',' #47433F'); "   
             onmouseup="p.onload();"   >

    <td><a href='MemPage.php?selected=<?php echo $f4?>'><?php echo $f4?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f1," ",$f2," ",$f3?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $f5?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f6,",",$f7,",",$f8?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f9?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f10?>/27</td>
    <td><a href='sms.php?selected=<?php echo $f4 ?>'>Send</td>
    <td><a href='http://www.goodfaithjobs.bugs3.com/upload/CRUZSEM2HW.doc'><?                
            php echo $f11 ?></td>

             <?php
             $i++;
             }
             mysql_close($conn);
             ?>
```

i was able to download the file successfully. because i specify a specific filename but my problem is what if i want to download a file wit different filenames? thank you in advance!

Comment: Where would you want the filename to come from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [downloading files using php and mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124450/downloading-files-using-php-and-mysql) - do not duplicate your own questions. You tend to now do this hourly and in multiple occasions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206530/downloading-file-in-server - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173468/about-force-downloading-using-a-url

Comment: i have a variable name $f11 that has a value of the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If `$f11` has the name of the file you should be able to do:

```
<a href='http://www.goodfaithjobs.bugs3.com/upload/<?php echo $f11; ?>'><?php echo $f11 ?></a>
```

Note that this assumes that `$f11` is not malicious. If this variable comes from the user consider making sure that it's safe (probably not too big a deal in this case since it's only used as a link).

Comment: thank you jim! :) i tried this code earlier but i forgot putting ; after <?php echo $f11?> thank you!

Comment: `$f11 = "<script>alert('XSS')</script>"`